# jQuery and hyperlink onclick written by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have some ugly PHP code which I will clean up later, but first the code should start working OK. Now it does not execute the post command. In other words, the script find.php will not be executed. Any ideas how to fix this problem? I just would like to use one hyperlink.

```
<?php

  print "<div><div>Play " . $i . "<span><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"$.post('find.php', { 'my': '$my_id', 'your': '$your', 'select': '$i' } ); $('html').css({ 'overflow': 'auto', 'height': 'auto' }); this.parentNode.style.display = 'none'; return false;\">Select</a></span></div></div>\n";

?>
```

Comment: Not trying to sound rude but mayhaps cleaning up your code in the first place will make debugging it easier? Code separation ain't that hard.

Comment: A couple of suggestions: try running `post` first with a static HTML code alone (rather than HTML created using PHP). Apparently, the only purpose PHP seems to serve here is to use the values for `$i`, `$my` and `$your`, and the rest can all be "outside" PHP. Also, please check the console for any errors. What notifications do you see there?

Comment: I think it is working fine

Comment: The code is on a dynamic div which I have created.

Comment: have u included jquery.js. i have tested it is working fine

Comment: did you check the console of your browser is it throwing any error if not then it suppose to show the ajax request in console of firefox or in networks of chrome.

Comment: please check the console of the browser is it throwing any error while loading or clicking on the link?

Comment: I could not see any error messages.

Answer (score 1):

In all honesty, you'd be better off cleaning up your code now. If you check your console, you'll more than likely get an error regarding jQuery not being loaded.

You should create a button with the required information appropriately:

```
<a href="#" class="mybutton" data-my-id="<?php echo $my; ?>" data-your-id="<?php echo $your; ?>" data-select="<?php echo $i; ?>">Select</a>
```

And create an event listener in jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // handle click
    jQuery(document).on('click', 'a.mybutton', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = {
            my: jQuery(this).data('my-id'),
            your: jQuery(this).data('your-id'),
            select: jQuery(this).data('select'),
        }
        //post
        jQuery.post('find.php', data);
        alert(data.select);
        jQuery('html').css({ 'overflow': 'auto', 'height': 'auto' });
     this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'none'; return false;

    });
});
```

From there, you'll have to clean it up to suit exactly what you need. If I were you, I'd start with the correct code/path in mind instead of *"looking at it later"*

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to create divs dynamically with hyperlinks executing jquery post. You can achieve this entirely in javascript itself  -

```js
function postFunc(my_id, your, i) {
  $.post('find.php', {
    'my': my_id,
    'your': your,
    'select': i
  });
}

function createDynamicDiv(my_id, your, i) 
{
  var node = document.createElement('div'); //dynamically creates a div
  node.setAttribute("style", "overflow: auto; height: auto"); //set css
  newlink = document.createElement('a');
  newlink.setAttribute('class', 'dynamicDiv'); //you might want to group all divs in a common class to add common css
  newlink.setAttribute('href', 'javascript:postFunc(my_id,your,i)'); //javascript: prefix on the href makes to interpret postFunc as a javascript function
  node.appendChild(newlink);

}
```

Call createDynamicDiv from your code to create a dynamic div.